# Can't preserve radio button data on form when value has characters in it

Tags: php, forms, session

I have a form made up of mostly radio buttons who's values are song titles, often with single quotes. Whether I use the HTML character code or the character, these values won't get stored in the sessions I created in order to repopulate the radio button when there is a form error. The titles without these characters get saved properly. I've tried using myqli_real_escape_string on the $_SESSION, but that doesn't work. My check to see if the session is equal to the value of the radio button proves false for these values even though look exactly the same to me. I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried using htmlspecialchars() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: Yes, I tried adding htmlspecialchars() to the value from the array before I used it to populate the radio buttons. No change. Then I tried using myqli_real_escape_string on my SESSION as well but I shouldn't really need that since the value of the radio button isn't input by a user. Neither works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried htmlentities()? I had an issue with single and double quotes and this fixed it.